# Date to Unix Time: Why don't this work?

Tags: php, mysql, date, yii, unix-timestamp

Am using Yii Wheels Date Picker to pick dates and I tried to save dates to database via Yii ActiveRecord it worked fine. Now I want to store Unix time-stamp not the Date itself. I have tried all suggestion from PHP Date class, to strtotime with no sucess. Yii's CDateTimeParser::parse  does not work too. Date inserted is always unix epoch so I know by that that my conversion does not work. my dates are in format `1972-03-02`

I have run out of ideas.

here is my code:

```
    protected function beforeSave() 
    {
        if(parent::beforeSave()) 
        {         
            //change date to Unix time stamp 
            $this->ccalstartdate = CDateTimeParser::parse($this->ccalstartdate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
            $this->ccalenddate = CDateTimeParser::parse($this->ccalenddate, 'yyyy-MM-dd'); 
        }
        return parent::beforeSave();
    }
```

**EDIT**
After running in debugger I can see conversion goes right but the values are not saved to database correctly. So something else is the cause. Up until AR save is called, the attributes are correct. So I guess this method is not the cause at all.

Comment: If nothing at all works, are you absolutely certain that the format is correct, that you're using `-` rather than an HTML &mdash;?

Comment: your doing `parent::beforeSave()` twise! maybe that's the case

Comment: @MarkBaker sorry for late reply I had to get a good sleep. can you break a bit what you mean in your question? I have put a format that I use and I use a dash that is `-` not the html equivalent, if that is what you were asking me to explain.

Comment: @tinybyte just recognized it now let me rectify that and re-test again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was fighting wrong battle. The code above works just fine. The problem was that I was using `zii.widgets.CDetailView` in my view widget to check the values. The widget was converting the thing and upon failing (was using its internal format) it printed that wrong number. I checked the database value and they are correctly stored as unix time stamps.
Thanks for everyone that tried to help. Next time I have to be more careful!